# laravel 5.2 pass data to registration view

Tags: php, registration, laravel-5

I'm using laravel 5.2 and I wrote this command to automatically add routes and views of authentication:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Now I want to pass data to registration view but I don't find where to do that, I assume that it should be with a code like that:

```
Route::get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
```

But in `routes.php` I have this:

```
Route::auth();
```

And in `Auth\AuthController` there are only two methods:

- validator
- create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

register user class is in this file

```
\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php
```

In laravel 5.2 in auth controller you see

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
```

and in this file see

```
   use AuthenticatesUsers, RegistersUsers {
    AuthenticatesUsers::redirectPath insteadof RegistersUsers;
    AuthenticatesUsers::getGuard insteadof RegistersUsers;
}
```

and  RegistersUsers class is in

```
\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php
```

If you use phpstorm ide you can go to the class name and press ctrl + left click
and php storm open your class .

Comment: thanks man! but is it a good practice to modify these files or should I use custom controlller to handle authentications ?

Comment: It is bad practice, because when you will update composer, it will revert all your changes.

Answer (score 2):

I new in Laravel, that's why my answer might be not right.

You can see what routes set "Route::auth()" in class Illuminate\Routing\Router in method auth().

AuthController use trait AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, this trait use trait RegistersUsers in namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth.

You can redeclare method showRegistrationForm() in AuthController:

```
public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    $data['info'] = "info";

    if (property_exists($this, 'registerView')) {
        return view($this->registerView);
    }

    return view('auth.register', $data);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did the same. Because making changes in vendor folder is bad practice. I would set this answer as Accepted...