# Add dynamic dropdown list on Laravel 5.2 registration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

i wanna add dynamic drop down list on my registration page
but i don't know how to do it cause i'm new with laravel.

I don't know where to start.

i want to put 2 drop down list on registration form

we get the value from a table

first is "group"
group consist of : 
1. Administrator
2. Users
3. Guest

second is "department" (disabled)
if the first drop down is Administrator or Guest, the second drop down disable.
But if we choose Users, then the department drop down enable and get the data from department table.

Comment: Provide your code and what you want to show in drop down list?

Comment: how many levels of dropdown you want?

Comment: i've edit my question @shuvrow and i want use 2 level dropdown in it

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do it in my opinion is to create a controller and a model.

```
php artisan make:controller YOUR_CONTROLLER_NAME_HERE

php artisan make:model YOUR_MODEL_NAME_HERE
```

After you do that it should be very simple.

Another nice library to pull down is

```
"illuminate/html": "5.*"
```

Put that in your composer.json in the require {} section.

Then you need to add the service providers in config/app.php under providers section like this:

```
Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider
```

And as the last part enter these two lines in the config/app.php under aliases section:

```
'Form'=> 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
'HTML'=> 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade'
```

Now include your model and view facade in your controller at the top like this

```
use App\MyModel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
```

In your constructor you need to inject your model into your controller like this.

```
private $myModel;
__constructor(MyModel $myModelParameter) {
    $this->myModel = $myModelParameter;
}
```

Now in your controller inside your call function(for example create()) add something like this.

```
public function create() {
    $myModelList = $this->myModel->lists('name', 'id');
    return View::make('myController.create')->with(compact('myModelList'));
}
```

And now finally onto the html/template file. In /resources/views/myController/create.blade.php for example add

```
    @extends('app')

    @section('content')

      {!! Form::open(['url' => 'myController/create', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
        @include('myController.partials.form', ['submitButtonText' => 'Create myController Item'])
      {!! Form::close() !!}

@endsection
```

Now inside your a new folder called /resources/view/myController/partials add form.blade.php

```
<div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('myModel_id', 'MyModel Selector :') !!}
  {!! Form::select('myModel_id', $myModelList, null, array('id' => 'myModel_id', 'class' => 'form-control input-sm')) !!}
</div>

<div style="clear:both;"><br /></div>

<div class="form-actions">
  <div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit($submitButtonText, ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
  </div>
</div>
```

This may seem like a lot of steps, but it makes everything really clean especially once your project starts getting large.  This will also work for your edit.blade.php  You just create a edit.blade.php file of course and include the form.  Since you are using models it will detect the correct settings for the model and pull in the values in the same way regardless.  Of course you can do more sophisticated stuff, but I recommend watching the free starter videos on laracasts.  It will show you stuff like this as well.

If you get stuck let me know and we can expand on this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

For Example you want to country list dynamic in Registration Form.

**In Controller**

```
class YourController extends Controller {

   protected $countryArray;

   public function __construct() {
       $this->countryList = ['' => 'Select Country'] + Country::lists('name', 'id')->all();
   }

   public function create() {

       $countryList = $this->countryList;
       return view('frontend.registration', compact('countryList'));
   }
}
```

**In Template**

```
<select id="country_id" name="country_id" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    @foreach ($countryList as $key => $country)
    <option value="{!! $country['id'] !!}"  !!}>{!! $country['name'] !!}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: i don't know how to put in on AuthController. I'm sorry, but i really new with this.

Comment: I think you have to 1st learn laravel documentation and then implement the code.

Comment: still do. but i don't understand about authentication and how to customize it. but, right know, i'm trying to code it, so i can show my code. thank you @php

Comment: btw, where is this code from? `data-code="{!! $country['code'] !!}"` i don't see it from the controller

Comment: Its unnecessary for you. I update my answer.

Comment: based on [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35389232/laravel-5-2-pass-data-to-registration-view), i add this code to my authcontroller `public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        $groups = [''=>'Pilih Group'] + group::lists('nama_group', 'id')->all();
        $jabatan = [''=>'Pilih Jabatan'] + jabatan::lists('nama_jabatan', 'kd_jabatan')->all();

        $data = array_merge($groups, $jabatan);

        if(property_exists($this, 'registerView')) {
            return view($this->registerView);
        }

        return view('auth.register', ['datas'=>$data]);
    }`

Comment: and i put this on my register.blade.php `<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('groupid') ? ' has-error' : '' }}"><label class="col-md-4 control-label">Groups</label><div class="col-md-6"><select name="groupid" class="form-control"><option value=''>Pilih group</option>@foreach($datas as $groupy)<option value="{!! $groupy->id !!}">{!! $groupy->nama_group !!}</option>@endforeach</select>@if ($errors->has('groupid'))<span class="help-block"><strong>{{ $errors->first('groupid') }}</strong></span>@endif</div></div>`

Comment: but this is happen _ErrorException in 61e3b9d18544518e5cbd501cd0755e21e8909aa4.php line 33:
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\laragon\www\lab1\resources\views\auth\register.blade.php)_